# How to print the input's number of copies?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
import re

t = int(input())
nentry = int(input())
def nitems():
    for number in range(nentry):
        pt = []
        items = input()[:10] 
        pt.append(items)
        if re.match("^[a-z]*$",items):
          print(pt)
        else:
          None
n = nitems()
```

Let's say for an instance, I'll input:

```
1
6
same
same 
same
different
different
different
```

I want it to output the number times the string is copied (The base number is 1. Don't mind the print and list) so the output should be:

```
2
```

The base number for each string is 1 and the input is three 'same' strings so the copies made were two. The same goes for the 'different' strings. So how am I going to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

t = int(input())
nentry = int(input())
cnt = Counter()

def nitems():
    for number in range(nentry):
        item = input()
        cnt[item] += 1

    v = defaultdict(list)

    for key, value in sorted(cnt.items()):
        v[value].append(key)

    for key in v.keys():
        print(key)

n = nitems()
```

demo:

```
1
4
alpha
alpha
omega
omega
```

output:

```
2
```